# Trying to do a LEFT JOIN, but ending up getting empty result

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried doing a LEFT JOIN (the one on the image second of the left). So basically I want all records from table A without the records from table B, so I want to take only the information from table B that crosses with table A. There is more info like book details in table B that I want to be able to extract, but I don't need of the rows from table B, just the extra info. I figure the best way to do this is with LEFT JOIN and this is the code I tried, but it result in a empty string/result:

`SELECT WF.*, W.* FROM WalletFrom AS WF LEFT JOIN Wallet AS W ON W.BookID = WF.BookID WHERE WF.BookID = 1360 AND W.BookID IS NULL`

What I am doing wrong?

Columns from Wallet:
 WalletID
UserID
BookID
OrderID
WalletStatusID
Win
WalletProductID

Columns from WalletFrom:
OrderID
BookID
Count
Win
WinTotal
Tax
WinEnd
DateTime
WalletProductID
[image]

Comment: in your example sql code, which one is table A and whick one is table b?

Comment: table A = WalletFrom, table B = Wallet

Comment: If `BookID` is your key, I think it cannot be `null` and `1360` at the same time

Comment: @Dimitar you are not explaining the reason behind your `WHERE` clause. I am afraid the statement `ON W.BookID = WF.BookID WHERE WF.BookID = 1360 AND W.BookID IS NULL` will never be true.

If `W.BookID` is equal to `WF.BookID`, then `WF.BookID can't be 1360` when `W.BookID IS NULL`

Comment: @JohnDavid, probably u r right, but I saw that on the image they do it this way, so that's why I tried with this code

Comment: how i suppose to do it if I only want the rows from table A and information from table B without the rows?

Comment: still unclear what you are trying to accieve. firs you say you need all records from table a without records form table b, then you say you say you need the details from table b without the rows from table b - kind of confusing. what do you mean without the rows?

Comment: haha, Well I don't want all the rows, I just want the rows from table A + the extra columns from table B, that make sense? :)

Comment: I think you should remove the `WHERE` clause completely

Comment: then why don't you use `inner join`?

Comment: " I want all records from table A without the records from table B, so I want to take only the information from table B that crosses with table A."  This makes no sense to me.  Sample data and desired results help!

Comment: @Dimitar Is this what you want? 

All records from **tableA** with the corresponding values from **tableB**, if there is no corresponding value from tableB it should still return the **tableA** record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up needing to do is just add an `AND` cause to my `JOIN` cause like this

```
SELECT WF.*, W.* FROM WalletFrom AS WF LEFT JOIN Wallet AS W ON W.BookID = WF.BookID AND W.OrderID = WF.OrderID WHERE WF.BookID = 1360
```

In order to not get duplicated records/rows. Thanks for everyone who have answer my questions you helped me to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

According to what you say in the comments, this sounds like inner join.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.BookID = TableB.BookID
WHERE TableA.BookiD = 1360
```

this gives you all the records from tableA that have a corresponding row in TableB without extra rows from TableB.

Ceck if this is what you need

#### Update

```
SELECT *
FROM Students AS S
INNER JOIN Grades AS G ON s.StudentId = G.StudentId
WHERE S.ClassId = 1360
```

Comment: instead of only 7 records I get 49 records from tableA and tableB

Comment: In which table are the 7 records which you expect it to fetch?

Comment: When I write `WHERE BookID = 1360` Table A are 7 records and Table B are 7 records as well and I want the end record to be only those 7 records, but when I add the join cause I end up with 49 results I don't have idea why?

Comment: I am just getting 7 records from TableA multiplied by TableB which is also 7 and I end up with 49 records

Comment: This is expected behavior - `INNER JOIN` makes a join with every possible row from both tables. What you say is that from TableB you want it to join **only** with 1 and with **any one**?

Comment: from Table B I want to get **only** the rows that matches with Table A, that make any sense? In other words I want to filter the rows to only match a book with an ID of 1360 for example which are a total of 7 rows and for those 7 rows I want to get information that is in Table B. Extended information from Table B.

Comment: I think you are missing an ID. See my updated answer, this gets all Students and grade information for a specific Class, Both, the Grade and the Student's table might have a `ClassId` but they are joined with `studentId`. I guess you would have to join it with another ID, not just `BookId`.

Answer (score 0):

You get empty result, because of `W.BookID IS NULL` clause, which is guaranteed to be not `null` by `left join` and its condition.

If you want only recrods from `WalletFrom` with `BookId` existing in `Wallet`, you could use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM WalletFrom wf
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Wallet
             WHERE BookId = wf.BookId)
```

Comment: I am just getting 7 records from TableA multiplied by TableB which is also 7 and I end up with 49 records and my idea is to just edn up with 7 records from both tables when I "join" them